# Drupal Search - Not searching for menu items

Tags: search, navigation

The default search module inside Drupal works perfect my project but the client wants to search for menu items too. The search module won't find menu items and I can't find a normal description or tutorial that demonstrates how to search them.

Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: Why would you search menu items, when menu items point at content on the site? Anyway, it might be doable with Search API.

Comment: I have a very good client with too much "logic" in his head :) .....

Answer (score 0):

As a work around I would try to creat a "funny" content type for each Menu Item and them redirect it to the original page link of each Menu Item.